# How can i link zend paginator with Jquery paginator plug-in?

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

How can I link `Zend` paginator with `Jquery` paginator plug-in ?

I don't want to refresh the pagination links. Only content should change.

Comment: Where I can find that plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which plugin are you talking about? There are dozens of jQuery paginator plugins out there.

Here's basically all you'll need in your controller:

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
$select = $db->select()
                ->from(array('t' => 'mytable'));

$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($select);

$paginator->setDefaultItemCountPerPage(100);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('p', 1));
echo array(
         'data' => $paginator->toJson()
);
```

And you're jQuery paginator might look something like this:

```
$("#mytable").paginate({
    url : "/controller/action/p/" + page_number
});
```

I can't really do a whole lot more for you since I'm not sure what plugin you're working with.